# Not able to access data in firestore .get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, get, google-cloud-functions

I'm a beginner web developer and am currently working on a blog website using nodejs/ejs, and firebase as my backend.

**PROBLEM**-
While fetching documents from firestore using the `.where().get()` method, I'm not able to get the inside fields of the documents.

**THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

NODEJS

```js
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  async function getDocument(id) {
    const doc = await db.collection('Posts').doc(id).get();
    const author = await db.collection('authors').doc(doc.data().author).get();

    const pre = await db.collection("Posts").where("artNum", "==", doc.data().artNum - 1).get();
    // ↑↑↑ this is where I get the previous document (for showing 'recomended article')
    
    
    return {
      author: author.data(),
      article: doc.data(),

      prev: pre.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
    // ↑↑↑ I map fetched Document in an array.
    }
  }

  getDocument(id).then(function (data) {

    res.render('post', {prev: data.prev, title: data.article.title, author: authorData, category: data.article.category, id: id });
  })
})
```

To test,
When I `console.log` the data In my EJS file, instead of showing the document data, it is logging - **[object Object]**

I've also tried it with -

```js
res.render('post', {prev: data.prev[0], title: data.article.title, author: authorData, category: data.article.category, id: id });
```

Can somebody please help me in where I'm coding it wrong?

Comment: Does `console.log(data.oneOfYourValues)` return an error ?

Comment: Please show the relevant ejs code. You also try `console.log(require('util').inspect(data))` before res.render to see what exactly your data is.